# Connect to remote server in T-SQL (SQL server 2008)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Does anyone have an example of a stored procedure which makes a connection to a remote server?

I have been searching the web and have so far discovered that it might can be done using `sp_addlinkedserver` and `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` but I haven't found a good example and I don't understand the documentation that well.

#### UPDATE:

None of the two first replies help me out, the closest I can get is using this:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = 'SiminnSrv', 
    @provider = 'SQLNCLI',
    @catalog = 'devel',
    @srvproduct = '',
    @provstr = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=my.serveradr.com;UID=my_user_name;PWD=my_pass_word;'
```

That actually makes me connect but when I query a table I get this message:

> Login failed for user '(null)'. Reason: Not associated with a trusted SQL Server >connection.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Essentially you create a linked server to the other server, and then provide login credentials to be used for SQL calls to that linked server. e.g. this will connect to "MyOtherServer" using a DomainAccount for that server with the username & password 'DomainUserName', 'DomainPassword'

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver 'MyOtherServer', N'SQL Server'


EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 
   'MyOtherServer', 
   'false', 
   'OtherServerDomain\DomainUser', 
   'DomainUserName', 
   'DomainPassword'
```

More Info [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190479.aspx) And [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189811.aspx)

Comment: Once my brain started functioning again I tried this again and realized what I was doing wrong. It is working perfectly now!

Comment: what is `MyOtherServer` is that where i put the server IP?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to connect to MSSQL Server 2008 through a linked server using the "SQL Server Native Client 10" (`SQLNCLI10`), but I had to use `sp_addlinkedsrvlogin` instead of `@provstr` to provide the connection details. This is based on the example from [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35943/How-to-Config-Linked-Servers-in-a-Minute):

```sql
EXEC master.dbo.sp_addlinkedserver 
    @server = 'MyServerConnection',
    @srvproduct = '', 
    @datasrc = 'SERVERNAME\INSTANCENAME',
    @provider = 'SQLNCLI10', 
    @provstr = ''

EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin
    @rmtsrvname = 'MyServerConnection',
    @useself = 'false',
    --@locallogin = 'someLocalUser' -- Use to restrict the connection to specific login
    @rmtuser = 'remoteUser',
    @rmtpassword = 'secret'
```

Querying this linked server:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM [MyServerConnection].[SomeDatabase].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Answer (score 1):

I may be late to the party, but I found the following links worked for me:

To perform the intial link, I used

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedserver @server='serverLinkPseudonym',@srvproduct='',@provider='SQLOLEDB', @datasrc='192.168.1.1';
```

Then, as I was logging in with Windows authentication, I added the Windows user (this cured my " Not associated with a trusted SQL Server" error)

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'serverLinkPseudonym', 'false', 'MACHINENAME\windowsLogin', 'lnkSrvLogin', 'lnkSrvPswd';
```

I also found that if I was going to run SQL Server Agent jobs that made calls to the LinkedServer, I had to add the following:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'serverLinkPseudonym', 'false', 'NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM', 'lnkSrvLogin', 'lnkSrvPswd';
```

For the sake of clarity: 
"192.168.1.1" is the IP of the server to be linked to.
"lnkSrvLogin" is a login on the server to be linked to, that has access to the database(s) that you need to access.
"lnkSrvPswd" is the password of that account.

If you are connecting to the linked server, using an account from the existing server, then you just use that account name in the sp_addlinkedsrvlogin command. eg:

```
EXEC sp_addlinkedsrvlogin 'serverLinkPseudonym', 'false', 'thisServerLogin', 'lnkSrvLogin', 'lnkSrvPswd';
```

Then test it:

```
SELECT * FROM [serverLinkPseudonym].[DBName].[dbo].[TableName]
```

Comment: Thank you! Great response as it includes @datasrc without this I couldn't figured out where to put the IP in and it would not connect. Once I added this worked perfectly great explanation of options too. Your the best man!

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to be able to query another server, you will need to create a linked server.

This page has a pretty thorough explination of how the sp works.
http://doc.ddart.net/mssql/sql70/sp_adda_17.htm

if you want to link to antoher sql server, just execute this:

```
sp_addlinkedserver @server='ServerName', @srvproduct='SQL Server'
```

@server is the name of the server you want to add.  @srcproduct is the type of server it is.  there might be some other things you'll have to do to hook up 2008 to 2005, but 2008 should work like this.

Comment: That link is a copy of SQL Server 7 Books on line... 3 versions and 11 years ago. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms130214.aspx